# Firestore callback inside of signInSuccessWithAuthResult to get extra userdata?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui

I'm using firebaseui, and it has the signInSuccessWithAuthResult callback which returns me the user.

So inside of there I want to call back out to a firestore document where I have more user profile data to use and save.

But I think this method is completing before the firestore .get() is and just never works.

Am I thinking about this problem wrong?  Is this just not the right place to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I think this method is completing before the Firestore .get() is and just never works.

You are guessing right, the operation of adding a listener is asynchronous and returns immediately and the callback from the Task it returns will be called sometime later. There are no guarantees about how long it will take. Depending on your connection speed and the state, it may take from a few hundred milliseconds to a few seconds before the authentication process is complete.

If you want to use the results of your authentication process, you must wait until the asynchronous operation is complete. This means that you can only use the results inside the listener callback itself.

Comment: So what's the best way to go about this then... like I have membership data stored in firestore and I'd like to attach it somehow at this point in the code and save as a cookie or localStorage.  I just want to avoid the situation where the authenticated page has no data if the callback happens over there, like want to load WITH all that profile data already.  Is there by any chance an article on best-prac for this with firebase?

Comment: ...maybe just an async\await to make it kinda "synchronous" (if that'll even work)

Comment: Yes, that's right, `await` is the solution to go ahead with.